# 'develop' or 'developing'

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, syntactic-analysis

Here are my constructions:

> 1. He has the ability to **develop** policies, procedures and solutions
>      that improve network disaster recovery and business continuity.
> 2. He has the ability to **developing** policies, procedures and
>      solutions that improve network disaster recovery and business
>      continuity.

So my question is, should I use 'develop' or 'developing'?

Comment: "Develop"  -- this one is fairly straight-forward.  The verb is "develop"; "developing" is the gerund form, which behaves as a noun.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> He has the ability to develop policies, procedures and solutions that improve network disaster recovery and business continuity.

Is the **correct** one because you want to use the infinitive without to (aka bare infinitive).
One reason for this may be that «having the ability to» basically goes down to «he is able *to*», which expects the bare infinitive.